# hibernate getCurrentSession().save() not save to database?

Tags: hibernate

I use getCurrentSession().save(item) to save item to database, but failed, how can I resolve this issue?
My code as below:
BaseDaoImpl.java:

```
public class BaseDaoImpl implements BaseDao {
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

ItemDAOImpl.java:

```
public class ItemDAOImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements ItemDAO {
@Override
@Transactional
public void addItem(Item item) throws DuplicateItemException {
    logger.debug("ItemDAOImpl.addItem() - [" + item.getItemNumber() + "]");

    try {
        Item itemCheck = getItem(item.getItemNumber());
        String message = "The item [" + itemCheck.getItemNumber() + "] already exists";
        throw new DuplicateItemException(message);
    } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
        getCurrentSession().save(item);
    }
}
```

data.xml:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.te.dc.*.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

data.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

data.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean  by failed? Exception?

Comment: no exception, just can not save to database.

Comment: I think hibernate not commit the record to database. If I use sessionFactory.opession() and use transaction manually, it can save to database.

Comment: What is this @Transactional? is it javax or org.spring?

Comment: getCurrentSession().save(item); Why you are saving in Catch block?

Comment: @Transactional is org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Comment: Becuase I throw exception in getItem() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
ItemDAOImpl.java:
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Item getItem(String itemNumber) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    logger.debug("ItemDAOImpl.getItem() - [" + itemNumber + "]");

    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Item where ItemNumber = :itemNumber ");
    query.setString("itemNumber", itemNumber);
    logger.debug("query string - [" + query.toString() + "]");

    if (query.list().size() == 0 ) {
        throw new ItemNotFoundException("Item [" + itemNumber + "] not found");
    } else {
        logger.debug("Item List Size: " + query.list().size());
        List<Item> list = (List<Item>)query.list();
        Item item = (Item) list.get(0);

        return item;
    }
}
```